# Obfuscar - different configuration for each module

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscar

my app consists of multiple projects, that have dependencies on each other.
Is it possible to set Obfuscar in such a way, so that for each of these projects, Obfuscar will use different settings (different level of obfuscation), while still keeping the dependencies between those project working in the output?

So far, I have tried setting the KeepPublicApi and HidePrivateApi different for each < module > specified in the obfuscar.xml settings file, where each is referring to dll of one project. However, after examining the output in DotPeek, it looks like that the same setting, defined at the top level of the xml file, gets used for every module, regardless how the parameters are set under it's xml node.

Is there some way to achieve what I am describing, or is using different obfuscation settings for each module not possible at this time?

Comment: Per module configuration isn’t supported nor planned. You can use multiple config files instead, each for an individual assembly.

Comment: I tried configuring different obfuscation settings for each module in it's own configuration fragment, but after inspecting the output dll's with DotPeek, same settings was still used for both of them :( Is there perhaps something that I am missing? Is this feature supported at all?